# iOS Calendar EventKit creating/accessing instance in an recurring event

Tags: ios, eventkit

In iOS Calendar, when we have an recurring event (eg. 7am to 8am DAILY from Jan 15 to Feb 15), we have the option to Edit or Delete a specific instance in the recurrence (so it only changes the event on that specific day but not the other recurrences). For example if I want to delete Feb 14th's event because I cannot make it. How to programmatically access this Instance/Recurrence so that I can edit/delete it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
After a lot of research I found, that you can edit/remove one instance in an recurring event.

If you fetch your events from your calendar, the recurring events has the same identifier, but other occurence dates.

Now you can edit/remove this one event and save it through the save method:

```
func save(_ event: EKEvent, span: EKSpan, commit: Bool) throws
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507295-save

With parameter "span : EKSpan" you specify, if you want to edit/remove only this one instance, or all future instances.

Please note, that the edited events are "undetached" of the parent events after save.

I know this question was old, but i wanted to share my solution.